# PHP & Jquery - Sending data between the client and server

Tags: php, jquery

I am trying to write code that sends a file path to the server, uses php to parse out each line into an array and returns the array to the client to have stuff done to it.

When I run my program it doesn't look like it is processing the php file as the echo that i put in for testing purposes is never called.

I know absolutely nothing about PHP so help is greatly appreciated!

Jquery:

```
$("#codelines").load('ParsePHPForDisplay.php?filename=DBManager.php');

    console.log($('#codelines'));
    pieces = $("#codelines").html().split("\n");
```

PHP:

```
<?php

class Parsing
{
    function ParseStuff()
    {
        echo('hi');
        $parsedFile = file($_REQUEST['filename']);
        echo($_REQUEST['filename']);
//        foreach ($parsedFile as $parsedFile_num => $parsedFile) {
//            echo"Line #<b>{$parsedFile_num}</b> : " .htmlspecialchars($parsedFile) . "<br/>\n";
//        }
        return $parsedFile;
    }
}

?>
```

A piece of my HTML:

```
<section id="codestuff">
    <h2>Code Lines</h2>
    <pre id="codelines">
    </pre>
</section>
```

**EDIT:**

Here is my PHP now:

```
<?php


        echo('hi');
        $parsedFile = file($_REQUEST['filename']);
        echo('test');
        echo($_REQUEST['filename']);
//        foreach ($parsedFile as $parsedFile_num => $parsedFile) {
//            echo"Line #<b>{$parsedFile_num}</b> : " .htmlspecialchars($parsedFile) . "<br/>\n";
//        }
        return $parsedFile;



?>
```

I get this error:

**Parse error**: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING, expecting T_FUNCTION in **ParsePHPForDisplay.php** on line **5**
.

Comment: There's no code calling ParseStuff()...

Comment: `$myParse = new Parsing(); $myParse->ParseStuff();`  Though for your purpose, you really don't need to make it in a class.  Seems like you came from a java background.  However, if you are only going to have one function, you may as well put it outside of a class scope so it runs when the page is loaded without the need to call it.

Comment: Jon's code should be somewhere in there. The class has to be instantiated then the function has to be called.

Comment: There's a bigger problem, Matt and Jon. He says he is trying to upload a file to the server. The PHP I see, is only loading a file that already exists, by its filename.

Comment: c# background :) I'm getting this error now: <b>Parse error</b>: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING, expecting T_FUNCTION in <b>ParsePHPForDisplay.php</b> on line <b>5</b><br>.

She - and not upload the file, just load it so I can display the contents.

Comment: @mavrosxristoforos I just assumed he hasn't gotten there yet, since he's obviously still learning the basic syntax of PHP.

Comment: @Yecats can you put an _edit_ type section underneath the main post with the PHP file you have now so we can see? ^^  And mavrosxristoforos, true, but I was with Matt in trying to help with the basics and have code execute at least for her ^^

Comment: Indeed, Jon.

@Yecats: sorry for the gender change. So what are you getting with the new code?

Comment: I get just this now: hitestDBManager.php @mavrosxristoforos - No problem, it happens often.

Comment: @Yecats From that code alone, I don't see where the parse error is.  Though, for readability, you don't need `()` surrounding the contents that you want to `echo`, `echo 'test';` would work just fine. ^^

Comment: Oh, good to know... thanks! What can I provide you to help determine the parse error? It looks like my echo 'test' or 'hi' are not showing up at all when the php is called.

Comment: What happens if you just write <?php echo 'test'; ?> in the whole file?

Comment: @mavrosxristoforos - It writes 'test' as anticipated.

Comment: Is that the entirety of the code for that page?  Because there isn't a parse error in it =/  Something else has to be off in there somehow.  Another side note, since we aren't in a function, you don't need to `return` anything, just the `echo`'s for getting the content to your JS.

Comment: As of php 4.3 files info is removed from $_REQUEST. Use $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"] instead of $_REQUEST['filename'] where "file" is the name of your form field.

Comment: Alright, so, to get this straight: You want to load a file into a Javascript array, by sending its filename to PHP, right?

Comment: @user1950929 Good job paying attention, she's not uploading a file, just passing a filename.

Comment: @Jon Well, I don't plan to have the echo be the actual end goal. (I was just doing that for test). I need to have the PHP return the contents of the file either as a string or an array to the jquery as there are numerous scripts (that do actually work for parsing JS files) that process the information and display it on the page. I feel like it has to be a problem with the PHP file as it isn't writing the echo's to the page. I removed everything and put:        echo '$_REQUEST['filename']; which printed out the proper PHP file name that I am trying to read from. The file is in the same folder

Comment: Sorry I misread the question.

Comment: @mavrosxristoforos That is correct. I just want to pull out the contents of a PHP file into a string or an array so that javascript can process it. (The javascript has been confirmed as working.)

Comment: @Yecats What happens if the only code in the PHP is `echo file_get_contents($_GET['filename']);`  Does it pass that correctly to the JS?

Comment: Looks like the solution Matt B. provided worked for me. Thank you guys very much for your help!

Comment: Sure, just make sure that the script becomes secure before publishing it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see why you would need PHP to parse the file into an array...just have it send the whole thing as a big string, then you can split it into an array of lines, if you need to, in Javascript once you get it from the server (e.g. `myString.split(/\n\r|\n|\r)` ).

Then, from PHP, you can just do:

`readfile($_REQUEST['filename']); exit;`

(note that this is not secure; you should add some conditions to the PHP code so it can only outptut files from a particular directory, for example. See PHP's `explode` function which will help you split the filename into an array using `DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR` as the delimiter).

Note that in PHP, a `return` statement doesn't cause anything to be output. Very often you'll get the value you need via a function that `return`s a value, but you still need to `echo` or `print` it.

Answer (score 1):

Alright, I believe the PHP you should use, since you are splitting the file into an array in the Javascript part, is:

```
<?php
  $file = file_get_contents($_REQUEST['filename']);
  echo $file;
?>
```

But before publishing this, you should check security issues, like the user loading files from other directories, using ../ in the filename, also not to fetch php files, etc.